# I keep getting StaticWebAssets.xml build error but I don't want them

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I keep getting this error when trying to build in VS 2022 Preview or `dotnet build` (but it doesn't happen in VS 2019):

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\projects\■■■■\■■■■.StaticWebAssets.xml" because it was not found.   ■■■■.■■■■.■■■■ C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  5100

The trouble is, these are APIs without any static web assets and I don't want to build or deploy static web assets. Is there a way to make this error go away?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Maybe try a "Clean Solution". After I did that, I didn't have any errors.

Comment: Why does that work?